# UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification get called more and more

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I am using this function in my view controllers to recognize if the app is active again and to refresh some data:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(becomeActive:)
                   name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                 object:nil];
```

This works for refreshing after getting active, but everytime the app gets back from background to foreground (inactive to active) it calls the function one more time.

So if I closed and opened the app 4 times, the function will be called 4 times!

*EDIT*: The function will be called this way:

1. close and open: function called 1 time (that's the way i want it)
2. close and open: function called 2 times
3. close and open: function called 3 times
4. close and open: function called 4 times

But it only have to be called 1 time after getting back in foreground. In some situation the app have to show an alert view after getting active and checking data. This alert view will be shown 4 times when the function will be called 4 times.

In the app delegate this function does nothing, but it is mentioned.

I am using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5! I also used `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`, but it also cause the same problem.

Comment: The problem is that you keep adding more observers, and each instance causes a call when the event occurs.  One way or the other, figure out to have only one instance of the observer enabled at any time.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know at when your adding self as an observer, but every time the app becomes active, you seem to be adding self as an observer, again and again. Thus the multiple calls.

You must only add your view controller as an observer once. Try using the controllers init: method. And, ensure that you remove the view controller as an observer in the dealloc: method.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestions. It's perfectly fine to register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` if you want a different object to be informed about the event. In fact, it can make a much better design. I agree with your assumption about the cause of the issue, though. The original poster must make sure to only add the view controller _once_ to the notification center and not every time the app comes to the foreground or goes to the background.

Comment: I really like this way using the NSNotifactionCenter because i can update the viewcontroller i want to update. I don't what you mean with adding it once to the notification center. Whats the best place to put in the nsnotification center. Actually it is in the view controller, could this be the problem? Should i put it to an own function? perhaps something which would only be called one time? do you have an suggestion for me?

Comment: I see, using this approach is fine, I made a wrong assumption. You must ensure that you only call [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:...] once. So, maybe place this call in your controllers viewDidLoad: method, and make 100% sure that you remove the controller from the defaultCentre when the controller is destroyed (by using [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:...]. Where are you currently calling [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:...]?

Comment: On second thought, the viewDidLoad: method is probably called again when the application becomes active (not certain about this). In which case you'd have to remove the object as an observer in the viewDidUnload method (as well as dealloc). You should use the init: method to add the object as an observer.

Comment: At first, the viewdidload is not called automaticly after getting active, thats the reason i use the NSNotificationCenter! This calls the viewdidload. i think the viewdidunload will only be called if the application quites completly, not when it gets inactive! The idea with the removeObserver seems to be a good idea, but where shall i put it.. perhaps when i add a new observer i could although delete the old one..

Comment: Add the view controller as an observer in the it's init: method, instead of viewDidLoad:. This way the view controller is only added as an observer once in it's lifetime. And remove it as an observer in the view controllers dealloc: method.

Comment: The dealloc method is only called if the app is really closed?!? But what is the "init"-method? -(id)init ?

Comment: you should at the **very least** read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1 they mention the purpose of the init method here...

Answer (score 0):

That's actually what this notification is supposed to do. If you need to be notified when application is started, use applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: This will not be called if the application is getting active again (or back to foreground).

Answer (score 0):

No i solved my problem.

The method which is called through the observer will not call the `viewDidLoad` anymore. so the `viewDidLoad` will only called once (on first application start up).

The function `getActive` which will be called through the observer now calls the methods which were firstly called out of the `viewDidLoad`.

I also put the `removeObserver` function to the `viewDidLoad`, which will only  be called, if the user will stop the app completely.

Thanks for the ideas and the help! Now i know a little bit more about making a multi-tasking app.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove addObserver in viewWillDisappear method. it is working for me.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```